# How to use tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D in Keras model? Got AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'output_masks'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, attributeerror

I have difficulty in using DepthwiseConv2D layer in my Keras model. I tried to look it up but many of the accepted answer regarding the problem is not to mix tf.keras.layers with pure keras.layers.

Is there any way I can use the tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D in my keras.layers model? Or is there anyway I can perform DepthwiseConv2D with Keras?

My Code:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input,Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import DepthwiseConv2D

inputs = Input((224, 224,3))
conv1 = Conv2D(16, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same')(inputs)
conv1 = DepthwiseConv2D((3, 3), padding='valid',depth_multiplier=1, strides=(1,1), use_bias=False)(conv1)
model= Model(input=inputs,output=conv1)
```

Comment: You can use keras.kayers.DepthwiseConv2D.